# Install Geometry stack from source

Tags: ros-fuerte, manifest.xml, pandaboard, source, rosws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am on an embedded ARM system (Pandaboard) so I don't have the geometry stack installed by default - specifically tf at the moment.  tf is a dependency on another package, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get ros to recognize that I have it.  I ran

*hg clone https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry*

into my workspace and then ran *rosws set geometry*.  However, still *rospack list* does not list tf as being installed.  I haven't had to *rosmake* any of the other packages I've done like this, but nonetheless, I tried that and it failed.  There are no manifest.xml files in the packages. Could that be why they aren't being recognized? How would I build those manifests if so? I also tried cloning it into my /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/ directory. still no-go.

Sorry if there is something very basic that I'm missing, but I've been stumped for a few days now. Thanks so much ahead of time.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59006/install-geometry-stack-from-source/) by [aman501](https://answers.ros.org/users/4218/aman501/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The tip of the geometry stack has already been migrated to [catkin](http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin). If you want to build it in ROS Groovy, you need to set up a catkin workspace. If you want to build the geometry stack from source in Fuerte, you'll need to use an older version like this one: https://kforge.ros.org/geometry/geometry/rev/cbfce76cb39f

Also, the geometry source has (very) recently been migrated to github: https://github.com/ros/geometry so it would be best to clone from https://github.com/ros/geometry/tree/fuerte_devel

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4